# What's the correct RegEx for this string

Tags: regex, vb.net

The link is https://instagram.com/p/Tud_psln-Yrn

I can't extract the underscore _ or the minus symbol -.

The underscore may or may not be in last part of the link as well as the minus symbol too. They also might be both in the last part of the link.

```
Dim rgxPhoto As New Regex("instagram.com/p\w*\d*\D*/>") 
Dim mchPhoto As Match = rgxPhoto.Match(strPageContent) 

Do While mchPhoto.Success 
   intPhotoCount += 1 
   mchPhoto = mchPhoto.NextMatch 
Loop
```

Basically the regex should extract the _and/or - from the last part of the link. It extract 542 URLS rightnow but the actual users photo count is 564. That's because of the urls with _ and - in them.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The correct regular expression to do what with the string?

Comment: I'm extracting photos from instagram.

Comment: @user3646458 You're not being clear. What is your expected output? To extract _ and - means your output will be _ and -. What do you want, the URLs with/without these characteres? Or the URLs with the characteres removed?

Comment: @user3646458 - I think the link you've provided is not working or missing some parts

Answer (score 1):

To match the last word in the url, use "[([\w\-]+)\/*$](http://regexr.com/3b1ef)"

To match the full url, use "[^https:\/\/instagram\.com\/p\/[\w\-]+\/*$](http://regexr.com/3b1e9)"

EDIT: To be in line with your code:

```
Dim rgxPhoto As New Regex("instagram.com/p/[\w\-]*/>")
```

Comment: Please mind the backslash in front of '-'. What do you mean it does not work? Can you show your code?

Comment: Dim rgxPhoto As New Regex("https://instagram.com/p/\w*\d*\D*/>")
            Dim mchPhoto As Match = rgxPhoto.Match(strPageContent)
            Do While mchPhoto.Success
                intPhotoCount += 1
                mchPhoto = mchPhoto.NextMatch
            Loop

Comment: Basically the regex should extract the _and/or - from the last part of the link. It extract 542 URLS rightnow but the actual users photo count is 564. That's because of the urls with _ and - in them. Sorry if this is confusing...

Comment: I tried using the latest regex you posted but it returns 0. Thanks for all the help. This regex stuff is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the - and _ with "[/[-_]/g](https://regex101.com/r/mM5aE3/1)" and then replace it with nothing.